# How To store multiple Object instances in an array?

Tags: mongodb

I'm working on a simple app but I got stuck figuring out how to store the data. Here is a sample of what I have:

** Collections **

Users

```
`{name: "NAME", username: "VALUE", email: "EMAIL", password:"PASS"}`
```

Ingredients

```
`{name: "NAME", category: "CAT", vegan:Boolean}`
```

** App Features **

App generates random recipe in the front end based on the Ingredients list.
Users can Save random recipe to their favorites.
Users can See favorite recipes under "Favorites" tab.

My question is, what would be a good approach to Store the user's favorite recipes? In theory, "Recipes" are just a few "Ingredient" Objects put together.

Maybe create a Favorites Recipe Collection that uses the "Ingredients" model

Users

```
`{name: "NAME", username: "VALUE", email: "EMAIL", password:"PASS", 
[Recipe(Ingrdient_IDs), Recipe]
```

}`

Comment: So I created a "Recipe" schema and I imported the "Ingredient" schema.

In the Recipe schema I added a field:
indgredients : [Ingredient.schema]

Answer (score 0):

I think, it should be good if you create model for recipe and connect it with user model like array of ids. Recipe model will help you if you want to add smth like views count. Then create ingredient model and connect it with recipe, with this you can easily add smth like description or calories.
So, create random recipes with random ingredients and when user add recipe to favourite just push *id* of recipe to **userFavouriteRecipes** array [more about push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/index.html).